# Converting React / Relay project to TypeScript — Parsing error on type import

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relay

I'm new to **TypeScript** and trying to convert a **React/Relay project** and I'm puzzled by a **parsing error** on a type import.

This is in an `Environment.ts` file and it's pretty copied directly from the **Relay Todo example**.

The **Relay example** uses **Flow** and .js extension.

```
// Environment.ts
import {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
  Observable,
  type RequestNode, // Parsing error: ',' expected.
  type Variables,
} from 'relay-runtime';
```

For reference, here's the fetchQuery that uses the two type imports:

```
async function fetchQuery(
  operation: RequestNode, // here
  variables: Variables, // and here
): Promise<{}> {
  let headers;
  let token = localStorage.getItem('WUDDIT_JWT');
  if (token) {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : 'bearer',
    };
  } else {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
  }
  return fetch('/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: operation.text,
      variables,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log('ERR', err));
}
```

Comment: Typescript compiles your code to javascript at the end and removes all types, just import all types and interfaces like another constant and function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has a different syntax for type-only imports:

You can either remove the type:

```
// Environment.ts
import {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
  Observable,
  RequestNode,
  Variables,
} from 'relay-runtime';
```

Or use import type in a separate import statement:

```
// Environment.ts
import type {
  RequestNode,
  Variables
} from 'relay-runtime';
// Environment.ts
import {
  Environment,
  Network,
  RecordSource,
  Store,
  Observable
} from 'relay-runtime';
```

Type only imports are useful for dead code elimination when you need only the types from some module. In this case there isn't much benefit of using type only imports.